# Repeated request to upgrade Microsoft Azure Tools for Visual Studio project

Tags: visual-studio

Each time I open Visual Studio Community 2017, I get the dialog below asking about upgrading the version of Microsoft Azure Tools.

This dialog appears 4 times (4 different projects), I click 'OK' each time and then everything seems to work fine.  However, next time I open the solution I have to repeat the process.

How do I resolve this once and for all?

Note that this project *was* created under a different version of VS (likely with a different Azure Tools) but that shouldn't be a permanent issue, I'd think.

[image: Dialog warning regarding version of Azure Tools]

Answer (score 0):

That's strange...

Have you tried upgrading the project this way:

In Solution Explorer, open the shortcut menu for the project node, choose Properties, and then choose the Application tab of the dialog box that appears

The Application tab shows the tools version that’s associated with the project. If the current version of Azure Tools appears, the project has already been upgraded. If you've installed a newer version of the tools than what the tab shows, an Upgrade button appears.

This may help as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-upgrade-projects-to-the-current-version-of-the-azure-tools

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your response.  Sorry my response has been so delayed.  I'm happy to report that the issue has gone away on its own.  I usually upgrade VS when I get the notifications so maybe one of them finally resolved it.  As a side note, I did try to follow your instructions but didn't see any version information on the Application tab apart from the Target Framework.